# Functions min(), max() or sum() with jsonpath

Tags: java, jsonpath

According to [JsonPath on GitHub](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) it shall be possible to access max(), min() or the sum() of an array but I dont know how. With this exampledata:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect it to work like

```
$..book.length
```

so im trying

```
$..price.sum
```

but that didn't do the job.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't have experience with this but it could be **sum(price)**

Comment: Have you reviewed the tests for usage examples?: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/blob/6c738c9aa2ca6023c6d8b4e63b9f43e7110bbb2e/json-path/src/test/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/function/NumericPathFunctionTest.java

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

> Functions can be invoked at the tail end of a path - the input to a function is the output of the path expression

Given this statement, you might expect the example JSON you supplied above to work with an expression such as `$.store..price.max()` but this expression does not work, instead it throws an error:

> Aggregation function attempted to calculate value using empty array

You can read more about that in this [JsonPath issue](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/191) on GitHub.

Meanwhile, here's an example which does work.

Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "price": [
      1.0,
      2.0
  ]
}
```

The JsonPath functions work as follows:

- `$..price.min()` returns `[1.0]`
- `$..price.max()` returns `[2.0]`
- `$..price.sum()` returns `[3.0]`

The above have been verified using the [online evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that. And the example also only works with the jayway implementation, so Im afraid there will be no way to use functions in the way I need to ..

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following :-

**For calculating SUM**

```
$.sum($.store.book[0].price,$.store.book[1].price,$.store.book[2].price,$.store.book[3].price)
```

**For min and max**

```
$.max($.store.book[0].price,$.store.book[1].price,$.store.book[2].price,$.store.book[3].price)

$.min($.store.book[0].price,$.store.book[1].price,$.store.book[2].price,$.store.book[3].price)
```

With this example data:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be possible to use a filter condition when using min/max like the following: `"$.max($.store.book[?(@.price < 10)].price)"` ?

Comment: @IoTuser Yes actually you can play around the same http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ here

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data contains a set of records and you need to perform aggregation on these sets. The example code uses a sum operation, and similar way of handling is for both min and max. Yet JSONPath only supports aggregation on a simple set and enumeration before aggregation, but it does not support aggregation on a set of records.

You can use SPL, an open-source Java package, to do it if you want a simple and easy alternative. You just need a single line of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =json(file("data.json").read()).store.book.sum(price) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as sum.splx and invoke it in a Java application as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call sum()");
st.execute();
…
```