# JsonPath max() issue empty array

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to find the max() for the below json string using JsonPath, but it throws an error `Aggregation function attempted to calculate value using empty array`. Please let know what will be correct JsonPath to get the max value.

```
[
    {"question":"pattern1","time":1},
    {"question":"pattern2","time":5}, 
    {"question":"pattern2","time":4}
]

$..time -- returns [1,5,4]
$..time.max() -- throws an error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functions min(), max() or sum() with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817156/functions-min-max-or-sum-with-jsonpath)

Comment: The solution would be to search the max value in the `$..time` result yourself.

Comment: can you please be more specific? what will be the exact jsonPath?

Comment: More specific would be to write the solution. You already have the `JsonPath` to retrieve every "time" in an array. Iterate the result and sum those value. There is no solution using `JsonPath` to sum those value. The structure is incorrect (as explain in the duplicate question)