# Sum of array in jsonpath

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, jsonpath

I am trying to use sum() function. I have gone through the [Functions min(), max() or sum() with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817156/functions-min-max-or-sum-with-jsonpath) link but this does not help me to solve the problem. I have tried to run the expression on  https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ this give me result for **$..price** with array of age, but when I want the sum of the age like **$..price.sum()** this give me an error **Aggregation function attempted to calculate value using empty array**. Can you please help me to write down the regular expression to get the sum of the age.

Comment: Read: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/191#issuecomment-186107010

Comment: How are we supposed to help you write a jsonpath expression against a json file we can't see???

Comment: @tomredfern i have given the URL for the json and on the same URL you can try the expression.

Comment: To the down voter , can you explain why the question is bad ?

Answer (score 0):

Install package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Then using [method reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), try:

```
var jp = require('jsonpath');

var data = {
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}

let sum = jp.query( data , '$..price' ).reduce( (acc,ele) => acc += ele ,0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am looking for the regular expression that can help me to utilize the sum() method.